# Assign Blender modifier values from list of stored values with Python

Tags: python, blender, modifier

I’m writing a script to reload FBX imports into the scene and recreate all the modifiers that were on the previous model, and I’m getting stuck with reassigning the values from the old modifier.

The script first records all the modifier parameter values that were on the model before reimporting, and stores them in a list.

When the new model is imported, the script creates a new modifier and assigns all the stored parameter values from the list, but this is where I get stuck.

Assigning parameter values with python is simple enough when you do it explicitly:

```
yourobjectname = "Cube" #for example
numberofsubdivisions = 3 #for example
bpy.data.objects[yourobjectname].modifiers["Subsurf"].levels = numberofsubdivisions
```

But if I try to do it in a loop like this:

```
for n, param in enumerate(dir(modifier)):
   stored_value = stored_param_values[n]
   modifier.param = stored_value
```

I get an error: modifier object has no property “param”

How can I properly access the parameters of a modifier to change their values in a for loop like this, without having to call out each parameter explicitly?

Comment: Probably you want `setattr(modifier, param, stored_value)`

Comment: Gave this a try, but I get the error that the attributes are ‘read only’